# Resilient HTTP client with name resolution update and active monitoring

Tags: java, http, https, dns, java-http-client

**I am trying to build an HTTP client based on `java.net.http.HttpClient` and I would like to have some control on the IP addresses resolved under the hood.**

I would like such mechanism to use all the IP addresses behind the host of the request. The underlying problem, I am trying to solve, is to react as soon as possible to an unavailability of a target IP. It could be done by doing active monitoring for each IP and use only the addresses available (at TCP, TLS or HTTP level) when sending an HTTP request. I also would like to load balance the traffic between all the IP’s and actively detect change in the DNS resolution. I am maintaining a long live connection to an external HTTPS service.

At the moment, only one IP address is used by the HTTP java client and pool of connections is maintained to target this IP.

I have built a work-around by using the IP address in the URL provided to the HTTP client and using a specific trust manager matching the expected name to keep the TLS validation. It has several limitation. In particular it changes the HTTP request which could impact the response you received depending on the server you target. It also forces to use one HTTP client by host you want to target. I have created a small [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nhenneaux/resilient-httpclient) to illustrate this workaround.

I explored a bit the HTTP client implementation and so far I have not found any way to implement such mechanism. In particular, I am stuck in `jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestImpl#getAddress` which is package visible and prevents any extension.

Such mechanism exists in Jetty HTTP client (see `org.eclipse.jetty.util.SocketAddressResolver`) or in HTTP Apache client.

**Is there any existing mechanism I could use to properly solve such problem? If none, is there a way to contribute or to submit a request of improvement?**